# input problems of using LSTM in python to forecast future value

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

There are two columns rainfall data and water level in my dataset and I want to predict the water level based of the past values using LSTM on python. My problem is do I need to include the past values of target column(water level) or just the rainfall data as input variables?

Comment: Hi @user161683, welcome to the site. How are you going to use the LSTM at inference time? Just to predict the water level at the next time point? Are you planning to predict more than one time step into the future?